# In Google Sheet, can we automate a manual action using Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I would like to know if in Google Spreadsheet we can automate a manual action on a daily basis?

Here is the context:

1. Every day, the google analytics API pull some campaigns data into a spreadsheet, the name of these campaigns respects a specific naming convention composed of 12 parameters separated by a ''_".
2. I create a new Tab where I am going to transform the data
3. In the new tab, I select the first column that contains the full campaigns names, then I go through **Data / Split text to columns** and I choose **"_"** as a separator.
4. After what, I obtain 12 columns.

Can I automate this action every day at "4 am" by using something like an embedded script code or something like that?

Comment: Welcome. Please include more details about your search/research about questions. Consider to take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn the basics about making questions on this site.

Comment: Yes you can automate that with apps script. Just open your spreadsheet and click on Tools/Script editor. In the script editor you can then go to the help menu to find some useful links.

Comment: Use a time based trigger:  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)